# Internally, how does a vector of vectors expand? c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, stdvector

Let's say I have a program like this:

```
#include<vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::vector < int > > vexample(2);
    vexample[1].push_back(0);
    vexample[0].push_back(0);
}
```

On the first line, I initialize a vector containing 2 zero-length vectors of ints. On the second line, I push_back() an int into the second vector, causing vexample[1] to resize.

What happens to vexample, the vector of vectors, on the next line when the first vexample[0] resizes due to pushback()? Is vexample[2] moved 4 bytes forward?

Comment: `vexample[2]` has undefined behaviour because it is an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: `vexample` is an array of addresses - each slot is a fixed size. When you `push_back` into one of the lower index entries, the entries in the array don't move around in memory. Rather it goes to the memory location at the defined address and resizes _that_.

Comment: @Kerrek SB sorry, that's a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of how vectors work internally.

A vector typically stores only 3 things internally (that is, on the stack):

- its size
- its capacity (that is, the maximum size up to which it can grow without resizing)
- a pointer to the array on the heap that stores the actual data

(Often, for performance reasons, implementations use 3 pointers instead, but conceptually it's the same).

This means that the part that can grow or shrink is stored on the heap. If you `push_back` elements into `vexample[1]` you will make it grow, and therefore the values of size, capacity and the pointer will be updated as needed, but this doesn't mean that they require more space on the stack: it's still 3 variables of fixed size, where "fixed" means it's determined at compile time.

If we assume that `size` and `capacity` are implemented as `int` and require 4 bytes each, and a pointer requires 8 bytes, then you have that a vector requires 4+4+8 = 16 bytes on the stack, regardless of the type and number of the  elements it contains, and `capacity * sizeof(T)` bytes on the heap. The amount of memory on the heap that is used can vary, whereas the one on the stack can't.

In your case, the elements of `vexample` are again vectors, and therefore each of them requires 16 bytes, plus the size of the allocated capacity. So, the memory layout is like this:

`vexample` takes 16 bytes on the stack. Of these 16 bytes, 8 are a pointer to an area of the heap where there's an array of 2 elements, each of which requires 16 bytes, so it's a contiguous block of 32 bytes: the first 16 are for `vexample[0]`, and the last 16 are for `vexample[1]`. Each of them contains a pointer to an array of `int`.

When any of these vectors grow, the data on the heap might need to be reallocated, but this doesn't "push away" anything else, because while it's true that the elements of the same vectors must be stored contiguously, the areas of memory corresponding to *different* vectors have no such requirement. So when you `push_back` elements into `vexample[1]` and force it to grow, neither `vexample[0]` nor `vexample` nor `vexample[2]` (if it exists) need to do anything. In particular, `vexample[2]` doesn't need to be moved because `vexample[1]` grows: on the contrary, if `vexample[1]` grows, then `vexample[1]` has to find a new place for itself.

All of this would be a problem if the variable-size part of a vector was saved on the stack, where everything is stored next to each other. But this is exactly the reason that you only store a pointer to the heap, and all the growing and shrinking happens there, where it doesn't cause any harm.

Comment: "then you have that a vector requires 4+4+8 = 16 bytes on the stack, regardless of the type and number of the elements it contains, and capacity * sizeof(T) bytes on the heap." - Neither of those statements is given to be true.  In fact they're more likely to not be.  Your statements about stack vs. heap are pretty erroneous and misleading as well.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: could you please explain why? They both seem correct to me.

Comment: First of all, the amount of memory required by a vector cannot be calculated that way.  `sizeof(vector<int>)` is not necessarily 16 even if the types it's composed of add up to that.  Second, the memory allocated to its storage is not necessarily `sizeof(T) * capacity()`.  The OS is in charge of that and it is unlikely to allocate exactly that much.  Finally, you can't say whether or not the variables within the vector are allocated on the stack or not--and the space allocated for the array of T may not be on the heap either.

Comment: @CrazyEddie Sorry, I'm quite confused now. About the first point: what do you refer to? Alignment? About the second point, I don't think the OS can decide to allocate less than the requested amount. How can the vector work if the OS doesn't do it? If the capacity is 16 and the OS assigns only 8, what happens when you try to write, say, 10 elements? And about your last statement ("the space allocated for the array of T may not be on the heap "), haven't you said the same in your answer? "Each vector contains a pointer to memory allocated on the free-store to hold its items".

Comment: @CrazyEddie However my previous comment has almost reached the maximum length. This is probably not the best place to discuss this. Maybe I should just ask a new question, with a link to my answer here... What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Each vector contains a pointer to memory allocated on the free-store to hold its items.  So nothing at all happens to `vexample`.  The data that `vexample[0]` may reseat its pointer, `vexample[1]` remains where it was until you change IT.  None of `vexample` elements get bigger or smaller.